# Validates inclusion failing for I18n in Rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord, internationalization

I have the following model.

```
class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  UNITS = [
            { name: "Unit" },
            { name: "Teaspoon" }
  ]
  validates :unit, inclusion: UNITS.map{|u| I18n.t(u[:name]) }
end
```

In the console. running the following command when the locale if :fr (french), yields the following based out of my locale file.

```
#Ingredient::UNITS.map{ |u| I18n.t(u[:name]) }
["Unité","Cuillère à café",]
```

Which is correct, however the validation fails for this, when I do the following.

```
Ingredient.create(quantity: 4.0, unit: "Cuillère à café")
```

When I manually check if the unit is included within the array, I get true. Why is this validation failing? Works correctly for english.

Answer (score 2):

Validators are defined when the class is loaded for the first time and do not change later on. In your example that means that

```
validates :unit, inclusion: UNITS.map{|u| I18n.t(u[:name]) }
```

is evaluated to

```
validates :unit, inclusion: ['Unit', 'Teaspoon']
```

and will *not* change to another locale in a later request.

It might work to assign a lambda instead on an array, like this:

```
validates :unit, inclusion: { in: proc { UNITS.map { |u| I18n.t(u[:name]) } } }
```